# React: Looping through an array within a state

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dictionary, reactjs

I am building a component within React. Everything seems to be working perfectly until I tried looping through a state.

Here is my component:

```
var BidItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        theMaxBid: '',
        theHighestBids: ''
      };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      var $component = this;
      $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data : {action: "get_max_bid"},
      })
      .done(
        function(response){
          $component.setState({
            theMaxBid: response.max_bid,
            theHighestBids: response.highest_bids
          });
        }
      );
    },
    render: function() {
      var dd = [{ids:"2"}, {ids:"5"}];
      var cc = this.state.theHighestBids;
      console.log(cc);
      console.log(dd);

      return (
        <div>
           <p>Max Bid: {this.state.theMaxBid}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });
```

This works, and within the render function both cc and dd output an array that looks like:

[image: logging the custom dd array and the cc array stored in the state]

When I loop through the cc array (which comes from the state) within the render function:

```
{cc.map(function(result){
            console.log(result);
          })}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cc.map is not a function
```

But when I loop through the below dd array, it works:

```
{dd.map(function(result){
            console.log(result);
          })}
```

Why can't I loop the state array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `componentDidMount` get's ran after the first render call, so the initial render won't have `this.state.theHighestBid` (tip: `highestBid`). The first time render is ran `this.state.theHighestBid` returns `''` which doesn't have the `#map` function.

Change `getInitialState`'s to `theHighestBid: []` and it will map through an empty array the first time, then call your AJAX when the component mounts, and then you'll get a response which will populate the state which will render a second time.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I loop the state array?

Because you don't have an array! `theHighestBids: ''` creates an empty string.

Change

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    theMaxBid: '',
    theHighestBids: ''
  };
}
```

To

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    theMaxBid: '',
    theHighestBids: []
  };
}
```

And make sure `response.highest_bid` is also an array.